# How we can set the browser zoom level in playwright beofreAll Hook?

Tags: playwright-typescript

`I have tried below code but it's not working accurately, any better solution would be more helpful.`

await page.evaluate(() => {
document.body.style['zoom'] = "80%"`your text`
})`your text`
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);``your text